# Why do comments sometimes become Null instead of being removed completely?

Tags: notebooks, syntax, input, comment

Consider the following definition:

```
Piecewise[{{(*comment*)-1, x > 0}, {0, True}}]
```

This is interpreted as intended, with the comment being simply removed, leaving only `-1` in the cell.

But if I enter it via `\[Piecewise]` followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> to get the following result, it's interpreted in a wrong way:

[image: screenshot]

Basically, the `(*comment*)` part is replaced with `Null` instead of being, as comments are to be, removed completely.

Interestingly, this only happens since Mathematica 8.0 (and is still present in 11.2.0), i.e. I don't reproduce it in 7.0.

So, what's going on here? Has the language or something changed? Or is it simply a front-end bug?

Comment: I could reproduce it in 11.2, but not in 12.0.

Comment: Looks like a in how Piecewise tag is interpreted. Here is a quick test: `InputForm@
 MakeExpression@
  StripBoxes@
   TagBox[GridBox[{{"\[Piecewise]", 
       GridBox[{{RowBox[{RowBox[{"(**)"}], RowBox[{"-", "1"}]}]}}]}}],
     "Piecewise"]`